# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TimeUserController::save(), 1 passed in Controller

Tags: laravel-9

I have an error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TimeUserController::save(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\lreport\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 3 expected

I want to insert data into the `TimeUser` table in the database. But before the data is stored in the table, I want to check first whether the `id_user` has been registered or not.

I'm trying to create a controller like this:

```php
public function save($id_user, Request $request){
        $id_user = TimeUser::findOrFail($id_user);
        if ($id_user == null) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $id = $request->id;
            $id_user = $user['id'];
            $time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $time_user['id'] = $id;
            $time_user['id_user'] = $id_user;
            $time_user['time_start'] = $time_start;
            TimeUser::create($time_user);
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        } else {
            $time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $time_user['time_start'] = $time_start;
            TimeUser::create($time_user);
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
        return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

And route in web like this:

```php
Route::controller(TimeUserController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('/timeuser/save', 'save');
    Route::get('/timeuser/save/{$id_user}', 'save');
});
```

in my blade.php

```
               <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/timeuser/save')}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">START</button>
                    </div>
               </form>
               <br>
               <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">GO TO CLASSROOM</button>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">FINISH</button>
               </div>
               <br>
               <table>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Duration</td>
                         <td>:</td>
                         <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Last Logout </td>
                         <td> :</td>
                         <td></td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
          </div>
```

What and how should I fix my controller part?

Comment: Which route or URI are you trying to access?  Is it `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: I tried to post, did I write it wrong?

Comment: There's a few issues in the code, but I'd suggest the main cause of your problem is that you're using the `save()` method for both your GET and POST routes. How are are you calling these URLs? What does your Blade/form look like?

Comment: okeyy, I've added it in my question. so i used: <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/timeuser/save')}}">

Comment: Then, something is off. Your HTML form `action` attribute points to a route that has **no** dynamic route parameters, yet your method `TimeUserController::save(...)` expects **exactly one** route parameter `$id_user`.

Comment: In addition, the shared error message is not in unison with the Controller source code.

Comment: ok thanks for the correction. so what should I correct?